If the integrals of $f$ over all sets in a generator are strictly smaller than the integrals of $g$, do we have $f<g$?
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\mathcal{E}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ be a generator of $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal{E})= \mathcal{A}$.
Let $f,g:\Omega\toℝ$ be measurable functions.
Then we have for $\sim\in\{<,\le,=,\ge,>\}$ that
$$
f\sim g  \text{ }\mu\text{-a.e. } \Leftrightarrow\left(
\forall A\in\mathcal{A}:\qquad\mu\left(A\right)>0\Rightarrow
\int_{A} f d\mu\ \sim\int_{A} g d\mu\right)
$$
I'm wondering whether if the equivalence also holds if we only use the generator elements in the right hand side:
$$
f\sim g \text{ }\mu\text{-a.e. } {?\atop \Leftrightarrow}\left(
\forall E\in\mathcal{\mathcal{E}}:\qquad\mu\left(E\right)>0\Rightarrow
\int_{E} f d\mu\ \sim\int_{E} g d\mu\right)
$$
The direction $\Rightarrow$ is trivial. The direction $\Leftarrow$ is however dubious, especially for the strict cases.
Towards a contradiction (for the case $f<g$) we could assume that $A\in\mathcal{A}$ is a set of measure $\mu(A)>0$ such that $f\ge g$. Then if we could construct $A$ in countably many standard set operations from elements of $\mathcal E$ then there might be hope, though I'm already uncertain whether we can keep the strictness. But the construction of $A$ might need uncountably many set operations.
What, if any, restrictions do we need to have the direction for $\sim\in\{\le,=,\ge\}$? Can we even have it hold for $\sim\in\{<,\le,=,\ge,>\}$?

Sorry! I misread the title.

@geetha290krm No problem, but if you have an idea to make it less confusing, feel free to edit this question. You're not the first one to have stumbled at my phrasing

Yes for $=$, no for $\leq, \geq, <$ or $>$.
Here is a counter-example for $>$. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A) = (\mathbb R, \mathcal B)$ with $\mathcal B$ the Borel sigma-algebra, and $E = \{(-\infty, x] : x\in\mathbb R\}$. Fix $f$ any positive, measurable and integrable function, and $g: x \mapsto f(x-1)$. Clearly
$$ \int_{-\infty}^x f > \int_{-\infty}^{x-1} f = \int_{-\infty}^{x} g. $$
However, is it easy to find an example where we do not have $f>g$.
Partial positive answer. Assume that $|f|$ and $|g|$ are integrable (you can replace the integrability assumption by non-negativity) and that $\int_E f \leq \int_E g$ for every $E\in\mathcal E$.
If you can approximate any measurable set by a countable disjoint union of sets in $\mathcal E$ for the measures $f(x)dx$ and $g(x)dx$, in the sense that for every $A\in\mathcal A$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $(E_n)_{n\geq 0}$ disjoint and in $\mathcal E$ such that $\int_{A\Delta \cup_n E_n} |f| \leq \varepsilon$ and $\int_{A\Delta \cup_n E_n} |g|\leq \varepsilon$, then by taking $\varepsilon\to 0$ we deduce that $\int_A f \leq \int_A g$, so your desired reverse implication holds.
In fact, you could weaken the assumption to
$$ \left| \int_A f - \int_{\cup_n E_n} f \right| \leq \varepsilon \ , \ \left| \int_A g - \int_{\cup_n E_n} g \right| \leq \varepsilon $$
without any condition relating $A$ to $\cup_n E_n$, although I expect that any reasonable proof of such an assumption would relate the sets $A$ and $\cup_n E_n$ in some way.

Interesting. I had some hope that a generator with $\bigcup_{E\in \mathcal E} E=\Omega$ or $\sigma$-finitness might work as condition, but that's out with this example.

To give some positive (though possibly trivial) examples:
If $\Omega$ is countable and we choose its one-element subsets as generator $\mathcal E$, then the statement holds for $\sim\in\{<,\le,=,\ge,>\}$.
If $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu) = (ℝ^n,^n,\lambda^n)$, i.e. the Lebesgue measure on the Borel sigma algebra on $ℝ^n$ and if we choose the set of all open sets as generator $\mathcal E$, then the statement holds for $\sim\in\{\le,=,\ge\}$.
For the second example note that $A:=\{f-g\ge 0\}$ is measurable and can be approximated by open sets from above, i.e. there exist open sets $O_1,O_2,...$ with $O_i\supseteq A$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda^n(O_i\setminus A)=0$.

What seems to make things work is that you can approximate (for the measures $f(x)dx$ and $g(x)dx$) any measurable set by a countable disjoint union of sets in $\mathcal E$; if that is the case, then your desired reverse implication holds. If this is not the case (like when $\mathcal E = { (-\infty, x], x\in \mathbb R}$), then it does not work anymore.

I have added this observation to my answer.
